# How MySQL IF (if else) ELSEIF (if else) statement can be used in a stored procedure?(mysql version 6.0.11-alpha-community)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is how I written a stored procedure in mysql version 6.0.11-alpha-community using if (if else) elseif (if else)  statements.

Tables are :

First Table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_smsnotifications` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `SmsIntradayPicks` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  `SmsAlerts` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  `SmsStrategyPicks` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And second table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_webnotifications` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `WebIntradayPicks` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  `WebAlerts` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  `WebStrategyPicks` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'False',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SP Query is :

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `marketprice_nse`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`(IN WSNUid VARCHAR(20), IN WSNColType VARCHAR(20), 
    IN WSCategory VARCHAR(10),IN WSNOptType VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN
    
  IF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'WEB' )
  THEN
         IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_webnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    -- if not exists (select 1 from tbl_webnotifications WHERE uid = WSNUid)
    THEN
        IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
                     VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False'); 
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
        THEN
        
        INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False');
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
        
    
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END ;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    -- then
             IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks' && WSCategory = 'WEB')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
               
          END IF;         
      END;
    
  
    
        
   ELSEIF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'SMS')
   THEN
   
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    -- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = WSNUid)
    THEN
        IF ( WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
        THEN
        
         INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                 VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False');
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                  VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False'); 
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
              INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
        
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END;
    ELSE
    -- THEN
             IF (WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;   
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks' && WSCategory = 'WEB')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                  
    
     END IF;
      END;
   
  END IF;  
  END;
  
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

While executing the above SP I'm getting this error

```
0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.001 sec
---------------------------------------------------

0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

Note Code : 1305
PROCEDURE marketprice_nse.webandsmsnotificationsinsert does not exist
---------------------------------------------------

Query: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`(in WSNUid varchar(20), IN WSNColType VARCHAR(20), in ...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
    else
    begin
    -- then
             IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
            ' at line 31

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

Note : the column names are same as I mentioned in SP

I think I'm not used properly the "if (if else) elseif (if else)  statements." statement

How can I achieve this?

(I'm new to MYSQL DB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your procedure.
`END` should be on the end of the `sp` and you have two `BEGIN`.

Somehow I made it working but I do not know if it is what you are looking for.
Check it and tell me if it helps ?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`(IN WSNUid VARCHAR(20), IN WSNColType VARCHAR(20), 
    IN WSCategory VARCHAR(10),IN WSNOptType VARCHAR(20))
    
BEGIN
    
  IF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'WEB' )
  THEN
         IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_webnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    THEN
        IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
                     VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False'); 
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
        THEN
        
        INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False');
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
        
    
    END IF;
    END IF;
    
          IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks' && WSCategory = 'WEB')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
               
          END IF;         

    
  
    
        
   ELSEIF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'SMS')
   THEN
   
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    -- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = WSNUid)
    THEN
        IF ( WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
        THEN
        
         INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                 VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False');
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                  VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False'); 
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
              INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
        
    END IF;
    END IF;

             IF (WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;   
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks' && WSCategory = 'WEB')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                  
    
                END IF;
                END IF;
 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes, It was helped for me and also I did some modification from my end (and it is also working fine tq for looking into it).

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `marketprice_nse`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `webandsmsnotificationsinsert`(IN WSNUid VARCHAR(20), IN WSNColType VARCHAR(20), 
    IN WSCategory VARCHAR(10),IN WSNOptType VARCHAR(20))

BEGIN
 
  IF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'WEB')
  THEN
  BEGIN
         IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_webnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    -- if not exists (select 1 from tbl_webnotifications WHERE uid = WSNUid)
    THEN
    BEGIN
        IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
        THEN
    
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
                     VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False'); 
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
        THEN
        
        INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False');
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_webnotifications(uid,WebIntradayPicks,WebAlerts,WebStrategyPicks)
        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
        
         END IF;
     END;
    
    
     
    ELSE
    BEGIN

             IF (WSNOptType = 'WebIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     -- begin
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'WebStrategyPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_webnotifications SET WebStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;
           
              END IF; 
              END;
              
    END IF;
     END;
    
    
    ELSEIF (WSNUid != '' && WSCategory = 'SMS')
    THEN
   BEGIN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = wsnuid ) = 0
    -- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_smsnotifications WHERE uid = WSNUid)
    THEN
    BEGIN
        IF ( WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
        THEN
        -- begin
        
         INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                 VALUES (WSNUid,WSNColType,'False','False');
                     
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
        THEN
        
          INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                  VALUES (WSNUid,'False',WSNColType,'False'); 
        
        ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks')
        THEN
        
              INSERT INTO tbl_smsnotifications(uid,SmsIntradayPicks,SmsAlerts,SmsStrategyPicks)
                        VALUES (WSNUid,'False','False',WSNColType); 
    
    END IF;
    END;
    

        ELSE
    BEGIN
    
             IF (WSNOptType = 'SmsIntradayPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsIntradayPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;   
                  
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsAlerts')
             THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsAlerts = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                     
                     ELSEIF (WSNOptType = 'SmsStrategyPicks')
                     THEN
                     UPDATE tbl_smsnotifications SET SmsStrategyPicks = WSNColType WHERE UID = WSNUid;  
                  
     END IF;   
     END;
     
   END IF;   
   END;
     
 END IF;  
       
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is what I changed.